# How to set lock screen wallpaper in OnePlus 2?

Tags: customization, oneplus-two

OnePlus 2 doesn't have the head of 'Themes' under 'Settings' menu. Nor is it giving an option of lock screen when choosing 'Set as' for a photo.

Comment: Related post on one plus forum for oxygen os https://forums.oneplus.net/threads/how-to-change-lockscreen-wallpaper.290408/

Comment: If you've root access, you should be change the current wallpaper (`/data/system/users/0/wallpaper`) to your desired wallpaper. Replace the file with your wallpaper (PNG file). Make sure the file name remains `wallpaper` and not `wallpaper.png` or any extension as suffix. Reboot and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

Soon this option will get added through OTA update! probably it will be releasing in 2-3 days. It's oxygen version 2.1.2